# How to change NGINX install location Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

My aim is to change directory of NGINX installation to run as a web server. Motive - custom compiled NGINX, with functions which doesn't come with standard.

I've compiled NGINX **from source** and as was suggested on [this page](http://www.bonnydoonmedia.com/index.cfm/blog/compiling-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-april-2016-update/), all configuration was pointed in the new location `/usr/local/nginx` when compiled. Default installation is at /usr/share/nginx.

After starting the service, NGINX still runs on the default installation.

I've tried to load nginx with new configuration `nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf` which breaks everything, returning error 404 for index.html.

Multiple attempts at searching, only shows up with changing site directory.

Is there a solid solution to specify from where NGINX loads?

**Edit:**

As suggested by John Ankanna below, the following fixed it:

1. `sudo mv /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/nginx.bkp` - just renaming the
   directory to recover current setup.
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/nginx /usr/share/nginx` - create symlink in place of original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu use a standard directory hierarchy. The command `man hier` will describe this for you. It is common for packages to create symlinks to place files in the correct place when the program expects them elsewhere.

Try Creating Symlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/nginx /usr/local/nginx
```

Comment: Copied your exact command and got `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/nginx/nginx’: File exists`, Also tried `ln -s /usr/local/nginx /usr/share/nginx` (trying to get /local/ to work instead of /share/, - default). Restarted NGINX for practicality. Flushed browser cache, and it still returns page from default installation. If you have a suggestion what to do in current situation, would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have to remove the `nginx` in the `/usr/local/nginx`  before doing please backup anything useful then proceed ...the link you are creating should not have the name with same `nginx` so conflicts ocured try removing in  the local